# jQuery BBQ, CakePHP and SSL/HTTPS

Tags: jquery, cakephp, ssl, hash, https

I'm using the [jQuery BBQ plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) for # hash browsing. The backend is CakePHP.

I have URLs of type `http://blabla.com/url#url1`, `http://blabla.com/url#url2` and based on that load controller actions `url1`, `url2` etc.

How to implement the following: `url1` should be HTTP-based and `url2` should be HTTPS, e.g. `http://blabla.com/url#url1`, `https://blabla.com/url#url2`.

Is it possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please revise this question with some formatting, line breaks and a coherent description of the problem.

Comment: For the first part of your question, here is an answer I wrote up to follow my own similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898135/is-there-a-cakephp-component-plugin-that-does-permanent-links-for-ajax-pages/5963122#5963122. However, it doesn't use the BBQ plugin, just some simple jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the the Ssl Component, define your conditions in the app_controller on the url, then use

```
$this->Ssl->force();
```

and

```
$this->Ssl->unforce();
```

to call your site with or without https

Comment: This one? http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/lemon/2008/07/07/component-for-forcing-a-secure-connection

Comment: @Tomalak Thanks for help. I've already implemented Cake SSL part and it seems working ok.

What I concern about is hash transition from [link](http://..#url1) to [link](https://..#url2) in the meaning: aren't they considered as different URLs?

Comment: it seems like you might to reconsider your solution, but in any case you will have to reload the page. i suggest you call a method that redirects you to the page with the parameter and rebuild the the url where it is send to depending on the parameter